# Compiling .less with .png assets with webpack for Django project

Tags: django, webpack, less

I have a folder for .less files that contains an img folder:

```
less
|   `-- img
|       `-- good-boy-cleaning.png
`-- index.less
```

the contents of index.less:

```
html {
    body {
        background-image: url("img/good-boy-cleaning.png");
        max-width: image-width("img/good-boy-cleaning.png");
    }
}
```

As part of a Django project, I would like to compile this into a css file in
`./myapp/static/myapp/css/` that references image files in `./myapp/static/myapp/img/`.

Is this possible?

The closest I've gotten is the following webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        myappcss: "./less/index.less",
    },
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("./myapp/static/myapp/"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "[path][name].[ext]",
                        context: path.resolve('./less')
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: "../"
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            // url: false,
                            importLoaders: 1
                        }
                    },
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which copies `./less/img/good-boy-cleaning.png` to `./myapp/static/myapp/img/good-boy-cleaning.png` and creates a css file in `./myapp/static/myapp/css/myappcss.03ee...97.css`, however, the content of the css file is:

```
html body {
  background-image: url(../f2215e467af7ba27555f.png);
  max-width: 264px;
}
```

the referenced png file is created, but it contains only:

```
export default __webpack_public_path__ + "img/good-boy-cleaning.png";
```

which isn't especially useful.

If I enable the commented out `// url: false,` then the png file is not copied to static, and the content of the css files is:

```
html body {
  background-image: url("img/good-boy-cleaning.png");
  max-width: 264px;
}
```

where the url ought to have been `../img/good-boy-cleaning.png` - assuming the png file had been copied.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-less-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/thebjorn/webpack-less-test.git",
  "author": "thebjorn <bp@datakortet.no>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "node-notifier": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "css-loader": "6.7.1"
  }
}
```

It probably goes without saying that I'm not a webpack expert, so perhaps I've misunderstood how this is supposed to work or skipped a vital option..?

Answer (score 0):

It seems asset modules provide the needed functionality out-of-the-box(ish). The following webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        myappcss: "./less/index.less",
    },
    mode: "production",
    devtool: false,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("./myapp/static/myapp/"),
        assetModuleFilename: 'img/[name][ext][query]',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                type: "asset",
            }, {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'less-loader',
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

generates `static/myapp/static/css/myapp.ccc94...634.css` containing:

```
html body {
  background-image: url(../img/good-boy-cleaning.png);
  max-width: 264px;
}
```

which is the expected url.

It also copies the png to `static/myapp/static/img/good-boy-cleaning.png` which is what I wanted.